# How do I format datetime for sails.js models

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have tried:

```
user.lastSeen = new Date().toISOString()
    user.lastSeen = new Date()
    user.lastSeen = new Date().now();
```

all have triggered a

```
{
    "ValidationError": {
        "lastSeen": [
            {
                "data": "2014-01-05T10:25:06.184Z",
                "message": "Validation error: \"2014-01-05T10:25:06.184Z\" is not of type \"datatime\"",
                "rule": "datatime"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There may be a typo when you generate User model for sail.js

Go to `$(projectDir)\api\models\user.js`

Change `lastSeen : "datatime"` to `lastSeen : "datetime"`